# Spelling of Kilometres on ArcGIS Pro scale bar?

Tags: arcgis-pro, internationalization, scale-bar

Being in Australia I like to see the spelling of "Kilometres" used on my maps in preference to "Kilometers".

In ArcGIS Pro 1.0 I have not been able to find an option to change the text used for units and so my scale bar looks as below.

[image]

I have looked at the Element Properties for the Scale Bar and was hoping that setting Region and language to English (Australian) might do it but it did not.

[image]

Does anyone know how to set a spelling of "Kilometres" on an ArcGIS Pro scale bar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the scale bar after you've inserted it.

Remember that the Ribbon options are based on whats highlighted/clicked/active. After you've clicked the scale bar, use the **SCALE BAR TOOLS** > **DESIGN** menu to modify the *label*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ESRI answered (via twitter)

Options>Units> Highlight Name and Change to the correct spelling.

[image]

source:
https://twitter.com/Esri/status/572928068475478017